# Run python in Applescript asynchronously

Tags: python, asynchronous, applescript

So I want a python script to start at the beginning of my AppleScript and while it's running, I want to do some other things. Something like this:

```py
set theResult to do shell script "python3 -c \"import time; time.sleep(60); print('finished waiting')\""

repeat with i from 1 to 60
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke (i as text) & ","
    delay 1
end repeat

return theResult
```

<sup>It would of course be something more complicated than `time.sleep()`, that's just for demonstration purposes.</sup>

Is there a way to keystroke the numbers while the python script is "loading"?

Comment: Your example `do shell script` would wait for the shell script to finish (it will also block the UI).  Without any details about what you are dong, you might take a look at using `NSTask`, which runs in the background and has various notifications.

Comment: @red_menace How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Not sure if this exactly what you want but per [TN2065](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2065/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003093-CH1-TNTAG5-I_WANT_TO_START_A_BACKGROUND_SERVER_PROCESS__HOW_DO_I_MAKE_DO_SHELL_SCRIPT_NOT_WAIT_UNTIL_THE_COMMAND_COMPLETES_), you can have 'do shell script' not wait by appending `&> file_path &` to the command (i.e. your first line should end like so… `\" &> file_path & "`.

Comment: To keystroke numbers you should coerce them to text and tell to "System Events". tell application "System Events" to keystroke (i as text & ",")

Comment: Your question was answered by @Mockman. My answer is repetition, as is the accepted answer. I upvoted his comment. With my examples I just wanted to provide a more visual answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the existing *code* from your question, albeit modified to work and using a lesser amount of time for testing, the following works:

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
do shell script "python3 -c \"import time; time.sleep(5); print('finished waiting')\" &>/tmp/result &"

repeat with i from 1 to 5
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke (i as string) & ","
    delay 1
end repeat

return (read "/tmp/result")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the example, which uses osascript & redirecting result to /dev/null for similar test:

```
do shell script "osascript -e '
     repeat 5 times
      delay 2
   display notification \"TEST\"
    end repeat
' &> /dev/null &" -- [end shell script]

delay 1
repeat 5 times
    display notification "OTHER"
    delay 2
end repeat
```

Other example - with redirecting result to temp file, and returning result from it after the shell script terminating:

```
set tempPath to (POSIX path of (path to temporary items from user domain)) & "result.txt"

do shell script "osascript -e '
     repeat 5 times
      delay 2
   display notification \"TEST\"
    end repeat
return \"Loading finished\"
' &> " & tempPath & " &" -- [end shell script]

delay 1
repeat 5 times
    display notification "OTHER"
    delay 2
end repeat

set theResult to read (tempPath as POSIX file)
```

Comment: I didn't accept your answer because the other one was closer to the thing I asked about.